# How do I get this function for quizzes to work?

Tags: python, function

I've been try to make a function for quiz questions but keep getting the wrong thing returned. I set the answer for 26 but even when I input 26 it prints out wrong.

Here is my code

```
def bst_q(question, answer):
    rq = input(str(question))
    if rq == answer:
        print ('Correct, Well done')
    elif rq != answer:
        print ('wrong')

bst_q('What is 13 times 2?',26 )
```

please help!

Comment: btw, why not: rq = input(question)  ?

Comment: Hi :) If an answer solved your Question, maybe set the answer as accepted. So others who search for a similar problem can find it.

Answer (score 2):

Variables have different types

- the variable `rq` is a `str`
- the attribut `answer` is an `int`

Also, do not use an `elif` with the opposite condition of the `if` just use an `else`

```
def bst_q(question, answer):
    rq = input(str(question))
    if rq == str(answer):
        print('Correct, Well done')
    else:
        print('wrong')
```

Comment: Yh I got that now, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to convert your answer to a string.

```
def bst_q(question, answer):
    rq = input(str(question))
    if rq == str(answer):
        print ('Correct, Well done')
    elif rq != str(answer):
        print ('wrong')

bst_q('What is 13 times 2?',26 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making here, is that you compare a `string` from `input()` with an `int` (26 in this case).

So your comparison is:
is 26 = "26"?

Which fails, as the number 26 is not equal to the string 26.
You could also add checks on the input type, if it is a sting and try to cast it to an int, but this should do the trick for the simple case.

Your program just needs a little adjustment:

```
def bst_q(question, answer):
    rq = int(input(str(question)))
    if rq == answer:
        print ('Correct, Well done')
    elif rq != answer:
        print ('wrong')

bst_q('What is 13 times 2?', 26)
```

The answer from @azro is right, in that you should not use the elif, but an else instead. Depending on what you want, you can either cast your answer to a string e.g.:
`bst_q('What is 13 times 2?', "26")`
or as I suggested, you cast the input into an int. Really depends on what you are trying to achieve here.